# What's the utility of the third argument of View.resolveSizeAndState()?

Tags: android

I went to the official doc page [android google official doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#resolveSizeAndState%28int,%20int,%20int%29), but it seems that they made a serious typo : we have no information about the third argument of the method. So I just wonder if someone already knows how to define this third int argument.

Comment: I grepped the Android source http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/view/View.java#View.resolveSizeAndState%28int%2Cint%2Cint%29  As you can see, the childMeasuredState is used as a binary mask for the Views' measure state.  Can't quite figure out how you might want to use that though ;)

Comment: OK, I can't get the link to work.  Just go to the page, find resolveSizeAndState and follow the link from there.

Comment: @Simon Thanks. Well, for I need it because Google recommands its use : on this page http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html#layoutevent

Comment: There's just using 1 (i.e. no effect since the return is ANDded with the argument.  Are you creating your own view group?  If not, then you have no children so just use 1 like they do ;)

Comment: No, just a single view (ChessBoard component). So I'll give 1 or just use resolveSize() . Thanks :)

Comment: That will work.  I've done plenty of custom views and never used this method, 99% sure it's only applicable to view groups.  Good luck.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `childMeasuredState` is the value returned by `View.getMeasuredState()`. A layout will aggregate its children measured states using `View.combineMeasuredStates()`. Here is an example:

```
int childState = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    final View child = getChildAt(i);
    if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
        measureTheChild(child);
        childState = combineMeasuredStates(childState, child.getMeasuredState());
    }
}
```

In most case however you can simply pass 0 instead. The child state is currently used only to tell whether a View was measured at a smaller size than it would like to have. This information is in turn used to resize dialogs if needed. In your particular case you shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Although it's an old and correct answer, Google's official documentation still missing the description for this field http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#resolveSizeAndState(int, int, int) while example here http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html uses 0 in one case and 1 in another without any explanation. Very confusing.

Comment: I am confused as well. I don't know what its for